# Is there a PHP equivalent for Groovy's Power Asserts?

Tags: php, unit-testing, groovy, assert

Is there a PHP equivalent for [Groovy's Power Asserts](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+1.7+release+notes#Groovy17releasenotes-PowerAsserts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has a built-in [`assert`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php) function that's a far cry from Power Asserts, but it's all you get. For something more powerful the only option is to use assertions such as those provided by unit-testing frameworks, but that's still not as good as Power Asserts.